# Scala generic type and implicit type class

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I am trying to understand scala implicits and their usage in type classes.
I have a generic trait FromString and a companion object defining implicit instances of FromString for standard types as specified below:

```
file: /src/main/scala/util/FromString.scala

package util
trait FromString[A] {
    def fromString(string: String): A
}

object FromString {
    def toFromString[T](p: String => T): FromString[T] = new FromString[T] {
        def fromString(x: String): T = p(x);
    }

    implicit val IntFromString = toFromString[Int](_.toInt);
    implicit val ByteFromString = toFromString[Byte](_.toByte);
    implicit val LongFromString = toFromString[Long](_.toLong);
    implicit val ShortFromString = toFromString[Short](_.toShort);
    implicit val FloatFromString = toFromString[Float](_.toFloat);
    implicit val DoubleFromString = toFromString[Double](_.toDouble);
    implicit val BooleanFromString = toFromString[Boolean](_.toBoolean);
    implicit val IntListFromString = toFromString[List[Int]](_.split(',').map(_.toInt).toList);

    def convertFromString[A](string: String)(implicit e: FromString[A]): A = e.fromString(string)
}
```

Now I can use the convertFromString function of the FromString object to convert string to standard types as shown below. This runs correctly.

```
file: /src/main/scala/top/Main1.scala

package top
import util.FromString._
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val d = convertFromString[Double]("4.5");
        val i = convertFromString[Int]("42");
        val li = convertFromString[List[Int]]("1,2,3");
        println(s"d=$d i=$i li=$li");
    }
}
```

However, when I try to use the same thing from a generic class, as shown below, it results in an error `could not find implicit value for parameter e: util.FromString[T]`

```
file: /src/main/scala/util/Knob.scala

package util
import FromString._ 
class Knob[T](val name: String, default: T){
    var value: T = default;

    def update(valstr: String) {
        value = convertFromString[T](valstr);
    }
}

file: /src/main/scala/top/Main2.scala

package top
import util.Knob
import util.FromString._
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val width = new Knob[Int]("Width",  3);
        width.update("100");
        println(s"width=$width");
    }
}
```

The implicits are defined in the object and I am guessing they are also available in the scope.

Answer (score 2):

The concrete type `Int` is known only in the line

```
val width = new Knob[Int]("Width",  3);
```

Before this line, the compiler does not know what the type `T` will be, and it cannot find and insert the `IntFromString` as an implicit argument anywhere. Thus, you have to pass the `IntFromString` from the invocation site in the `main` to the use site in `Knob.update`. For this, just add the `FromString` typeclass to `T`:

```
class Knob[T: FromString](val name: String, default: T) {
  ...
}
```

General rule when programming with generic types and typeclasses: the concrete typeclass instances must be inserted "at the end of the world", in the line where the generic type parameters (like `T`) are fixed and become concrete types (like `Int`). You have to pass those typeclass instances all the way from the site where the concrete types can be determined to the generic code that uses the typeclass instances.

---

```
trait FromString[A] {
  def fromString(string: String): A
}

object FromString {
    def toFromString[T](p: String => T): FromString[T] = new FromString[T] {
        def fromString(x: String): T = p(x);
    }

    implicit val IntFromString = toFromString[Int](_.toInt);
    implicit val ByteFromString = toFromString[Byte](_.toByte);
    implicit val LongFromString = toFromString[Long](_.toLong);
    implicit val ShortFromString = toFromString[Short](_.toShort);
    implicit val FloatFromString = toFromString[Float](_.toFloat);
    implicit val DoubleFromString = toFromString[Double](_.toDouble);
    implicit val BooleanFromString = toFromString[Boolean](_.toBoolean);
    implicit val IntListFromString = toFromString[List[Int]](_.split(',').map(_.toInt).toList);

    def convertFromString[A](string: String)(implicit e: FromString[A]): A = e.fromString(string)
}

import FromString._

class Knob[T: FromString](val name: String, default: T) {
    var value: T = default

    def update(valstr: String) {
        value = convertFromString[T](valstr)
    }
}

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val d = convertFromString[Double]("4.5");
        val i = convertFromString[Int]("42");
        val li = convertFromString[List[Int]]("1,2,3");
        println(s"d=$d i=$i li=$li");


        val width = new Knob[Int]("Width",  3)
        width.update("100")
        println(s"width=$width")
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to bind `T` to be of type `FronString` (this would make Knob.value to be of type `FromString`, which I don't want), infact `T` can be of any cencrete type. I want the compiler to supply implicitly the corresponding `FromString` object in the update function if such an object is there.

Comment: @Sudhanshu What does *"bind `T` to be of type `FromString`"* mean? There are no type universes in Scala, and no stratification of types. `T` cannot be *"of type `FromString`"*. It can only *require the typeclass `FromString`*. If you don't require the typeclass, then you cannot use `convert` (shouldn't it be `convertFromString` anyway?). Your `Knob.value` is of type `T`. Adding the `FromString` typeclass doesn't change the type of `Knob.value`.

Comment: I am still learning scala and kind of forgot about context bounds. I understand what you meant. After doing the change you suggested, I am getting an error `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type util.FromString[T]`

Comment: @Sudhanshu I've added the full code example. Compiles and runs just fine, without any errors. The error message that you're getting is probably caused by some minor issue with the imports.

Comment: The imports seem to be the problems. Will try to resolve them. Thanks